# How can I turn on camera flashlight in Symbian, using Qt Mobility

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, qt-mobility, flashlight

How can I turn on camera flashlight in Symbian, using Qt Mobility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [QCameraFlashControl](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/qcameraflashcontrol.html)

Specifically call setFlashMode with QCameraExposure::FlashTorch.

Comment: ( my nokia c5 have qt mobility 1.0, so i decide to download flashlight app

Answer (score 1):

To get the current flash mode use

QCamera* camera = new QCamera;
QCameraExposure* cameraExposure = camera.exposure();

FlashModes flashMode = cameraExposure->flashMode();

To set a flash mode (for example always on) use

QCamera* camera = new QCamera;
QCameraExposure* cameraExposure = camera.exposure();

cameraExposure->setFlashMode(QCameraExposure::FlashTorch);